# Blank-Bootstrap Switch active tab

Tags: bootstrap, active

I'm new to joomla just used Bootstrap alone before.

So how do you change the active tab in the navbar?
Without joomla I just made an own .php file for every site and made the 
tab  manually active.

But how do you do that using joomla? Here one has just one php file?!

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Heute anwesend</a></li>
    <li><a href="../joomla/index.php/anmelden">anmelden</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Section 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Gästebuch</a></li>
```

Here I can just set one "section" to active. I hope you guys understand my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla has its own method of creating tabs. Please refer the following links for this:

- http://itprism.com/blog/106-bootstrap-tabs-accordion-slides
- https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Using_the_JHtmlTabs_class_in_a_component

Please have a look and let us know if this helps.